# compressed data corruption with tlmgr (TeXlive 2018)

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I installed TeXlive 2018 on Windows 8.1 a few months ago (when it just came out). I updated the installation a few times since that initial install, without any problems.

Today I wanted to get the latest files and I did the usual:

```
tlmgr update --self,
```

followed by

```
tlmgr update --all
```

This is what I get (seems similar to a problem reported two week ago for Windows 10).

[in fact it is the third run of `update --all`, before it failed for the `abnt` and `acmart` packages, hence the 
`skipping forcibly removed package abnt`
`skipping forcibly removed package acmart`
messages]

```
C:\Users\goossens\goossenswork\lwarp>tlmgr update --all
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/
tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2018/tlpkg/backups
skipping forcibly removed package abnt
skipping forcibly removed package acmart
[  1/103, ??:??/??:??] update: alegreya [14131k] (48170 -> 48339) ... xz: (stdin
): Compressed data is corrupt
TLPDB::_install_package: Decompressing C:\Users\goossens\AppData\Local\Temp\z5z_
0BM_nz\YYsHMQWGq8/alegreya.tar.xz failed
tlmgr.pl: Installation of new version of alegreya failed, trying to unwind.
Cannot open tlpobj file: C:/texlive/2018/tlpkg/tlpobj/alegreya.tlpobj at C:/texl
ive/2018/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 70.
```

Any hint what the problem could be?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Trying to re-install the package acmart (which was forcibly removed by tlmgr update in my second try) and using a  Swiss repository, I still get a similar error message.

```
C:\Users\goossens\goossenswork\lwarp>tlmgr install acmart
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: acmart [6470k]
tar: Skipping to next file header
untar: untarring C:\Users\goossens\AppData\Local\Temp\u3V8gSH7KSIgE7FQYbxB/acmart.tar failed (in C:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist)
TLPDB::_install_package: untar failed
tlmgr.pl: package log updated: C:/texlive/2018/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
```

Comment: You could try another mirror. If this doesn't help I suggest to write to the texlive mailing list.

Comment: Hello Michel :-)

Comment: I just did an update now and got: `....[ 3/66, 00:07/01:29:18] update: alegreya [14131k] (48170 -> 48339) ... done
[ 4/66, 00:54/04:43] update: apxproof [565k] (47665 -> 48377) ... done....` so it does look like an issue with your mirror

Comment: Always in these kind of cases, please attach the output of `tlmgr update -v --all` otherwise we cannot debug it. As David wrote, I can only guess that it was a problem with your mirror, or some intermediate proxy.

Comment: My sincere wishes to `Michel Goossens`...

Answer (score 2):

It is probably some other version of xz installed in your system causing all the trouble. You need to just inspect all your system PATH entries and remove or disable all the xz executable copies each time you install or update TeXlive or any of its packages. For example if you have MinGW installed then you can temporarily rename C:/MinGW to C:/_MinGW and everything should install correctly. I hope it will help.

Comment: Welcome. // Please remove this reply and post it as a separate question. You can link to this question, if necessary.

Comment: How should I do it though? And why just adding an answer to the first question provided by Google is not good enough?

Comment: "I have the same issue" - "answers" will be deleted. We try to do it this way here: 1 question = 1 complete problem. 1 answer = 1 concrete solution. We try to avoid chit-chat. Unusual, but you'll like it over time.

Comment: I have edited my answer to be a direct answer to the initial question and a probable direct solution to the initial problem. I hope it is good enough. You can just delete the whole thing otherwise, I will not bother going any further.